# why is this 'click' event listener not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

This is my html :

```
<div class="document">
    <div class="documentInputwrapper">
        <textarea id="documentInput" class="documentInput" placeholder="Start typing here..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="componentDropDown">
        <p class="components">Header</p>
        <p class="components">sub header</p>
        <p class="components">text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
const components = document.querySelectorAll(".components");

function addComponents(pComponentName){
    console.log(pComponentName);
}    
components.forEach((component, index) => {
    console.log(component, index);
    component.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        console.log(component);
        const componentName = component.innerText;
        addComponents(componentName);
    });
});
```

For some reason, the component name is never outputted to the console, whenever i click any member of the class 'component'. I've checked for typos, as far as i can see there are none. Also i've tried both ()=>{} and function(){}, neither work. I really don't know where I am going wrong. The components and indexes are outputted at the beginning, so they are definitely rendered. and I've also made sure that the document has the eventlistener DOMContentloaded. I really don't know why the code doesn't work. All the other javascript code works after this, that i've not included.

Comment: Your code seems to work as desired [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e391phwb/) which would mean some other code is causing your predicament. Consider providing the code that causes the unexpected behavior to occur.

Comment: @Wongjn, this code does not work for me as the component name is not outputted to the console, every time i click the component

Comment: @Wongjin, i realised the dropdown menu closed before the click could be registered and that is why the function did not happen, so I prevented the defualt behaviour and now it works. Thank you so much !